# why use the underlying type of an enum class to define a variable?

Tags: c++11

I saw the following comment in some code.

```
 * The implementation uses custom pointer types to save space, and
 * to preserve addresses if the underlying container is resized.
 * For instance we define `enum class id_t : uint32_t {}`
 * instead of (id *)
```

Question> Why use enum class type can preserve address?

Answer (score 1):

This technique is sometimes known as "relative addressing" or "offset pointers."  For example, if you have an array:

```
int arr[1000];
```

And you want to store two locations in it, you could do:

```
int *x = &arr[40];
int *y = &arr[100];
```

But instead you do:

```
uint32_t x = 40;
uint32_t y = 100;
```

Then to dereference one of these "pointers" you say `arr[x]` instead of `*x`.

To avoid having to keep `arr` around, you can encapsulate the offsets:

```
template <size_t N>
class offsets {
public:
    int& operator[](size_t idx) const { return _arr[_off[size_t]]; }

private:
    int* _arr;
    std::array<uint32_t, N> _off;
}
```

And now you have saved space on a 64-bit platform, because you store 64+32*4 = 192 bits, instead of 256 bits for four regular pointers.

You also don't need to update them if `_arr` changes (e.g. to grow or shrink the array).  This could be a meaningful optimization if the number of stored offsets is large.

Comment: This doesn't explain why they are using `enum class id_t : uint32_t {}` instead of just `uint32_t` though.

Comment: @zett42: Presumably because it lets them "name" their relative pointers.  In my example I showed an array of N pointers accessed by index, but perhaps the application wanted to access them by names instead.